# Overwrote some of my saves with .reg file... But some later, inaccessible entries remain? How to restore?

Tags: dex

Since Dex's saves are stored in the registry, I made a backup of my saves as a .reg file, but accidentally ran it without realizing it would overwrite my saves. It did, *and* it didn't.

It was a backup of my first 100 saves, but then I checked my registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Dreadlocks Ltd\Dex, and I still have saves 200 to almost 300, just that my game can't seem to register their existence.

Anyone know how to get my saves fully back?